# How to cook oatmeal?

Tags: boiling, oatmeal

I bought a pack of oatmeal and it didn't have any instructions on how to cook it and I have no clue what I am doing and I don't want to disappoint mom.

Comment: What kind of oatmeal do you have?

Comment: It says soft oatflakes on the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is instant oatmeal, just add boiling water (ratio water to oats 2/1) and let it sit for 5 minutes. If it not instant, same ratio of water to oats, boil for 5 minutes while stirring, remove from heat, cover and let sit for 5 minutes.
I googled "how to cook oatmeal" and found several  similiar ways.

Comment: Salt! You forgot the salt.

Comment: You don't need the salt, I was just being as basic as possible. I DO use salt, though.

Comment: I would use milk - or part milk, part water (unless it’s an “all in one” instant package. And without fruit or something sweet, at least served on the side, Mom may get a nice texture, but a rather bland taste.

Answer (score 0):

Common "rolled" oats are flattened into fat disc-shaped units; "quick" oats are rolled and then further sliced thin to cook faster. "Steel cut" oats are just cut into small hard pieces like short rice grains.

For quick oats, add about 2:1 water to oats, and cook until done to desired softness, which should be a few minutes. For rolled oats, cook longer and maybe add a little more water to account to evaporation. For steel cut oats, go up to 3:1 or even 4:1 on the water, and cook for 30 minutes or more (or let soak overnight and cook for 10 minutes). They'll need some salt, but not much.